# アセンブリでプログラムが終了してしまう

Tags: assembly

アセンブリの練習のためにbmi(Body Mass Index)を計算するプログラムを書いています。
最初に`your_height`を表示してからstdinを読み込もうとするのですが、`your_height`の最初の1文字を表示した後、すぐにプログラムが終了してしまいます
なぜなのでしょうか?

環境: Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 (gccでのコンパイル時に`-m32`をつけてx86として実行)

```
.data
emessage: .string "file open error\n"
your_height: .string "Please enter the your height  (m):  "
your_weight: .string "Please enter the your weight  (kg):  " 
newline: .string "\n"

.bss
tmp: .skip 128, 0x00

.text
.global main
main:
    push %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    pushl $your_height
    call print
    call read
    pushl $your_weight
    call print
    call read
    movl -4(%ebp), %eax
    movl -8(%ebp), %ebx
    divl %ebx
    divl %ebx


read:
    movl $3, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $tmp, %ecx
    movl $64, %edx
    int $0x80
    cmpl $-1, %eax
    je write_error_message
    movl %eax, %esi
    pushl %esi
    ret

write_error_message:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $emessage, %ecx
    movl $16, %edx
    int $0x80
    call exit

exit:
    movl $1, %eax;
    xorl %ebx, %ebx;
    int $0x80

print:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl 4(%esp), %ecx
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $1, %edx
write:
    cmpb $0x00, (%ecx)
    je ret_func
    int $0x80
    incl %ecx
    jmp write


ret_func:
    ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

アセンブリ言語の質問を書かれるのであれば、プラットフォームをきちんと明記しておいた方がいいでしょう。同じx86系のCPUを使っていてもシステムコールの書き方などはガラリと変わってきます。

ここでは、`int $0x80`を使っているのでLinuxである可能性が高いと言うことで、その前提で回答を書いておきます。

今Linux用のアセンブリを動かせる環境がないので他にも修正すべき点があるかもしれませんが、少なくとも`print:`周りは次のように修正する必要があります。

```
print:
    movl 4(%esp), %ecx
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $1, %edx
write:
    cmpb $0x00, (%ecx)
    je ret_func
    movl $4, %eax ;<-システムコール番号は、`int $0x80`の直前で毎回設定
    int $0x80
    incl %ecx
    jmp write

ret_func:
    ret
```

Linuxのシステムコールでは結果がeaxに帰ってくるので、その内容は`int $0x80`の前後で変わってしまいます。eaxに設定するシステムコール番号は、毎回`int $0x80`の直前で設定しなおしてください。