# アセンブリがsegmentation faultで止まる

Tags: assembly

[アセンブリでプログラムが終了してしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28668/%e3%82%a2%e3%82%bb%e3%83%b3%e3%83%96%e3%83%aa%e3%81%a7%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a0%e3%81%8c%e7%b5%82%e4%ba%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86) の質問を投稿したものです
アセンブリでbmi(Body Mass Index) を計算するプログラムを練習のために書いているのですが途中でsegmentation faultを出して止まってしまいます。

なぜなのでしょうか?

OS: ubuntu16.04 x86_64 
gcc `-m32`をつけて32bitとしてコンパイル

```
.data
emessage: .string "file open error\n"
your_height: .string "Please enter the your height  (m):  "
your_weight: .string "Please enter the your weight  (kg):  " 
newline: .string "\n"

.bss
tmp: .skip 128, 0x00

.text
.global main
main:
    push %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    pushl $your_height
    call print
    call read
    pushl $your_weight
    call print
    call read
    movl %esp, %eax
    movl 20(%esp), %ebx
    divl %ebx
    divl %ebx
    pushl %eax
    call print
    call exit


read:
    movl $3, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $tmp, %ecx
    movl $64, %edx
    int $0x80
    cmpl $-1, %eax
    je write_error_message
    movl $tmp, %esi
    pushl %esi
    ret

write_error_message:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $emessage, %ecx
    movl $16, %edx
    int $0x80
    call exit

exit:
    movl $1, %eax;
    xorl %ebx, %ebx;
    int $0x80

print:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl 4(%esp), %ecx
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $1, %edx
write:
    cmpb $0x00, (%ecx)
    je ret_func
    movl $4, %eax
    int $0x80
    incl %ecx
    jmp write


ret_func:
    ret
```

Comment: デバッグされてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 2):

直接の原因は `read` でスタックフレームを破壊している状態で `ret` しているためです。
そこを修正すれば直る・・・と言いたいところですがそれだけでは期待したものにならないでしょう。

システムコール `read()` はファイルデスクリプタからバイト列を得るものです。
`123<改行>` に対して得られる結果は `31` `32` `33` `0A` ですから
身長・体重の｢数値」を入力する目的には更に `atoi` とか `atof` 相当の処理が必要です。
提示コードの落ちる原因である `pushl %esi` はおそらく関数呼び出し命令列の一部で
あろうと推測されますが、不完全なのでプログラムそのものがそこで死んでいます。

[c](/questions/tagged/c) コンパイラとか `C Runtime Library` が目の前にあって即使える状況では、
オイラは `atoi` `strtol` 相当の関数を直接アセンブラで書きたくありません。
（[c](/questions/tagged/c) で相当関数を書いたことはあります。整数演算だけなのでたいして難しくない）
`atof` `strtod` 相当の関数は [c](/questions/tagged/c) であっても書きたくないです。ましてやアセンブラをや。
（精度落ちとか丸めとか考慮する内容がいっぱいありすぎる）

ここは [c](/questions/tagged/c) ライブラリ関数を呼び出す手順を学んでみてはいかがでしょうか。
それはそのまま [c](/questions/tagged/c) 関数から呼ばれるアセンブラ関数を作る知識にもなります。
現代的にはアセンブラだけで完結するソフトを作るのは非常に稀だと思います。

x86 の｢関数呼び出し規約」は cdecl や stdcall などいっぱいあるので厄介です。
最初は [c](/questions/tagged/c) コンパイラの書き出すアセンブラを読んでみるのがよいでしょう。
最適化を(強く）かけると熟練者にも読めなくなりますから、最適化なしをお勧めします。

```
gcc -S -O0 example.c
```

Comment: 質問とは直接関係のないことですが、Linuxでのx86アセンブリを学ぶのにオススメの書籍などがあれば教えてください

Comment: オイラが ABI ってのを知ったというか学んだのは 8086 の時代で、そのときの資料は Microsoft C のマニュアルでした。組み込み系で SH や RX や MN103 のアセンブラ書く時の資料はメーカー純正コンパイラのマニュアルとチップのマニュアルでした。 x86 の資料となると、やはり msdn 文書でしょうか。とりあえず `x86 ABI` で検索してみるといろいろ出てくると思います。それら資料を見ながら、コンパイラの吐き出したアセンブラを読むのが早道だと思うです。